# Adding dashed line in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I want to display two maps in the print composer: a main one, and another showing a zoomed in section of the main map. I've drawn a rectangle over the original region and want to add two dashed lines connecting the rectangle to the zoomed in section of the map, but I can't figure out how.

I tried using an arrow without an arrowhead, but there isn't an option to make it dashed. I've also tried drawing a flat dashed rectangle, which works but is quite fiddly.

Does anyone know of an easier way to perform this simple task?

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS <= 2.4 this isn't possible, but the good news is that it's [implemented in the current development](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/fec27111ee30d97a63d9a203a0f2609cbd30fc20) version and will be available in QGIS 2.6. You can now style lines in the composer using all the styling options available for line layers in the map canvas, including dotted and dashed lines.