# Adding extent lines to overview maps in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, map-overviews, extent-indicators

Is there a way of automatically adding lines to overview maps in QGIS 3+ print composer?

At [Creating zoomed in portion of map in print composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/154025/115) it is done manually, but since I have several overview maps and might want to shift their position, to also change lines manually would not be an option.

[Adding dashed line in QGIS print composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/109495/115) says that this feature will be available in v2.6 but does not explain how to do it.

[image: what I want to achieve]